# What are the common causes of Prefetch Abort errors on ARM-based devices?

Tags: debugging, arm, raspberry-pi3, abort, prefetch

My C program is running on bare metal Raspberry Pi 3B+. It's working fine except I got random freezes that are reported as Prefetch Abort by the CPU itself. The device may work fine for hours then suddently crash. It's doing nothing special before it crashes, so it's not predictable.

The FS register (FSR) is set to 0xD when this error happens, which tells it's a Permission Error : http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0087e/Cihhhged.html

Other registers : FAR is 0xE80000B6, LR is 0xFFFFFFFF, PC is 0xE80000B6, PSR is 0x200001F1

My program uses FIQ and IRQ interrupts, and use the all the four cpu cores.

I don't ask for specific debug here since it would be too complicated to dive into the details, but are you aware of common causes for Prefetch Errors to happen ?

Comment: The `FAR` and `PC`  are an ARM instruction (not a real address) and LR is a crazy value.  This indicates a stack overflow (or at least problem), as well you seem to be in `FIQ` mode?  Have you set the stack for the `FIQ`?  This may again be related to a kernel stack overflow as will the FSR register.  For instance Linux keeps the 'task control block' as a mask via an 8k page stack/TCB and if this over/under flows, code will grab a garbage MMU (mm) structure and bad return values such as modes and PC values, etc.

Comment: Interesting, I remember my program wasn't working at all during an earlier development stage, it worked only when I lowered the size of some buffers -- which were allocated on the stack. I didn't thought about it again until your message. Would simply doing "char *buffer=new char[SIZE]" instead of "char *buffer[SIZE]" be enough for freeing some stack space and using heap instead ?

Comment: IRQ is used to interact with an I2S device, FIQ is used for handling a serial input. I haven't tried to use it with IRQ instead. I haven't set any special stack for the FIQ since I use a bare metal framework which does some abstraction job for me

Comment: Absolutely, `char *buffer=new char[SIZE]`, but this will possibly leak.  Is SIZE fixed?  Some library functions can not be used (like `new`) in an interrupt reliably.  You have to do this elsewhere.  The `new` and all heap management need to run 'atomically'.  If your mainline does a `new` while the interrupt does a `new`, you may crash occasionally; the lists/buckets that `new` manages will get mixed up.  You should limit C/C++ library calls in an interrupt.  `memset()` `strncat()`, etc are okay, but not much else.

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on these comments and the one below my answer - hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I've swiched to heap-based buffers and it didnt crashed yet (I need to test it for some more days maybe I was just lucky). SIZE is fixed, it's a single-time alloc at the start of the program so it's not very complex to manage.

Comment: Make sure SIZE is big enough too, otherwise it'll still break.  And if you don't know how big is big enough, put in a runtime check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your code is multi-threaded (multi-core, indeed) and the crash is not predictable, I'd say that the prefetch abort is almost certainly being caused by memory corruption due to a race.

It might help if you can find out where the abort is being generated.  Bugs like this can be extremely hard to track down though; if the code always crashes in the same place then that could help, but even if it does and you can find out which address is suffering corruption, monitoring that address for rogue writes without affecting the timing of the program (and hence the manifestation of the bug) is essentially impossible.

It is quite likely that the root cause is a buffer overrun, especially given your comments above. Really you should know in advance how big your buffers will need to be, and then make them that size. If whatever algorithm you're using can't guarantee a limit on the amount of buffer it uses, you should add code that performs a runtime check on the buffer and responds appropriately (perhaps a nicely reported error so you know which buffer is overflowing). Using the heap is ok but declaring a large buffer as `static` is faster and leak-free, providing the function containing the buffer is non-reentrant.

If there are data access races in the mix too, note that you will need more than data barrier instructions to solve these. The data barrier instructions only address consistency problems related to pending memory transactions. They don't prevent register caching of shared data (you need the `volatile` keyword for that) or simultaneous read-modify-write races (you need mutual exclusion mechanisms for that, either as provided by whatever framework you're using or home-brewed using the `STREX` and `LDREX` instructions on armv7).

Comment: I'm ensuring that the read/write regions are correct when the cores do the work by using Data Memory Barriers (it's the instruction "mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c10, 5"). Some buffers are setup by the core #0, it tells to the other cores they can start working, then it waits for them to finish before taking the result. I see there are other types of barriers : Data Synchronization Barrier, Instruction Synchronization Barrier... ( http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14041.html )

Maybe they would be needed to ensure full coherency ?